# Replace substring using regex with condition

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I need to replace every substring in a string that matches a regex, something like this:

```
std::string result = boost::regex_replace("my# random *#string ##"
        , boost::regex("#([^#*]*[*][^#*]*)#")
        , tr);


    std::string tr(const boost::smatch &m) 
    { 
       std::string replaceString;
       bool ret = CheckIfWeNeedToReplace(m[0], replaceString);

       if (ret) 
          return replaceString; // replacing
       else
          return m[0];          // remain the same
    }
```

e.g. for string `"my# random *#string ##"` there is one match for regex `"#([^#*]*[*][^#*]*)#"`, that is `" random *"`, and if `CheckIfWeNeedToReplace` return false, then the string remain the same, if not - it will be something like this `"my#NEW SUBSTRING#string ##"`

My code doesn't work, what did I do wrong ?

Comment: `#([^#*]*[*][^#*]*)#` doesn't match anything in `my# random ^#string ##`... What are your matching criteria?

Comment: @Robin, fixed it, my matching criteria: any string 1) between '#' symbol 2) contains only one '*' symbol, 3) doesn't contain '#' symbol in it

Comment: We need to see your `CheckIfWeNeedToReplace` function